# Create a selection from alpha channel on a layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections

I have two layers and an alpha channel:

[image]

And I would like to select an area on the "Layer 1" with a contour from the alpha channel, namely I want the "red" area be inside the selection. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load an Alpha Channel as a Selection....

Hold the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> key down and click the thumbnail for the Alpha Channel in the **Channels Panel** to load the Alpha Channel as a selection

Or.... Choose `Select > Load Selection` and pick the Alpha channel from the second dropdown list:

[image]

---

With the above in mind as to how to load a selection from an alpha channel....

For *all* selection methods... the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key will *add* to a selection, or the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key will *subtract* from a selection.

---

So.. if a a selection for layer 1 is active....

- to ***add*** the alpha channel (the red) to the active selection, hold down <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keys and click the Alpha Channel thumbnail in the Channels Panel.
- to ***subtract*** the alpha channel (the red) from the active selection, hold down <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> keys and click the Alpha Channel thumbnail in the Channels Panel.

---

I, personally would merely use a **layer mask**....

- Load the Alpha channel as a selection.
- Highlight Layer 1 in the **Layers Panel**.
- Click the **Layer Mask button** on the bottom of the **Layers Panel** to add a layer mask to Layer 1.

You can then select, paint, filter - whatever - on the *mask* which can often be easier than figuring out the right key combos, inverse for a channel, and procedural steps in order to get a selection of exactly what you need.

---

If you don't want a full Layer Mask, you can utilize the **Quick Mask Mode** -- load the Alpha Channel as a Selection, then tap the `Q` key on the keyboard, there's then a Quick Mask (by default you'll see red everywhere that is *not* part of the selection - red means "hide" in Quick mask). Just paint - black for hide, white for show. You can make selections, run filters, etc all in quick mask mode as well.When you're done, just tap `Q` again and you'll have a selection.

---

Truth is, there are numerous ways to create then add to or subtract from a selection. Which one works best in any given situation will vary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just needed to get a selection on the "Layer 1" to work with it.

Comment: Ahh, then I may have gone overboard in explaining `:)` oh well, more info never hurt anyone.

Comment: Completely agreed with you!